# sed issues when working with tab? Should I use awk instead?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, macos

```
cat file.tsv| sed '1icolumn1    column2   column3    column4    ...' > file2.tsv
```

I am using sed to add a first line (header labels) for a `.tsv` file. The labels should be tab separated. I have been using a literal tab to separate the strings.

I double checked the string several times. However I keep running into the issue of a tab being lost

For example, instead of getting `column1    column2   column3`. It often ends up as `column1    column2column3`. Then when I try to fix it, it ends up as `column1column2   column3`.

Is there another way to add tabs such as using '\t' (I tried, but it did not work) which is less prone to errors? Would `awk` be a better alternative?

Comment: tab is no different than `X` or any other literal character to sed, what you show will work 100% of the time, assuming those chains of spaces are tab chars. Whatever problem you're experiencing, it's not the sed command in your question. Maybe it's whatever you're using to see the content of the file or maybe there's some odd control chars in your replacement string?

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I checked the file and indeed you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to use `printf` command:

```
printf "column1\tcolumn2\tcolumn3"
```

and here is the result:

```
column1 column2 column3
```

with tabs:

```
printf "column1\tcolumn2\tcolumn3"|od -ax
0000000   c   o   l   u   m   n   1  ht   c   o   l   u   m   n   2  ht
        6f63 756c 6e6d 0931 6f63 756c 6e6d 0932
0000020   c   o   l   u   m   n   3 nul
        6f63 756c 6e6d 0033
0000027
```

(check 0x09 in the code above, this is TAB)

and your command will become:

```
cat <(printf "column1\tcolumn2\tcolumn3\n") file.tsv >file2.tsv
```